# Moving Hamburger Menu to Right side of screen is not working

Tags: html, hamburger-menu

I am trying to move a hamburger menu button to right side on mobile devices. Currently it is in center.

I tried to add `float:right` , `right:0` and `position:relative`  to `mobile-nav-toggle` and `navbar-mobile` class.

But unfortunately, nothing helped me.

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/darshaninfo/c6w0rbon/22/)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+menu+right+mobile+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor HERE instead of on an external site

Comment: Can you show your html and css?

Comment: @AJAnde It is in JSFIDDLE provided

Comment: Change  "justify-content-lg-between" with  "justify-content-between" or another size that you want for mobile.

Comment: @DA Great.... It worked like charm... A Big big thank you... I played with mobile-nav-toggle and navbar-mobile ... but it didin't come in mind to check for div containing navbar... Thank you...